# overloading a float to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, overloading

I have a function, processing a 1D numpy array, like this:

```
def f(arr):
    arr=asarray(arr)
    #process data as numpy array
    #...
    return arr
```

With `asarray` I allow to call the function with a list as `f([4,5,6])`. Now, I would like to "overload" the argument also to a single float, so that I can use `f(4)` instead of `f([4])`.

This is a standard numpy feature, since you can call `np.sin` as `sin(array([4,5,6]))`, or as `sin([4,5,6])` or as `sin(4)` as well. I came up with this code, that works at least in simple cases:

```
def f(arr):
    arr=asarray(arr)
    if arr.shape is ():
        print 'arr is a single float/int/etc'
        arr = array([arr])
    #process data as numpy array
    #...
    return arr
```

Is this the standard/correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`np.atleast_1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html).

```
>>> np.atleast_1d(5)
array([5])
>>> np.atleast_1d(np.arange(2))
array([0, 1])
```