# numpy arrays dimension mismatch

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am using numpy and pandas to attempt to concatenate a number of heterogenous values into a single array.

```
np.concatenate((tmp, id, freqs))
```

Here are the exact values:

```
tmp = np.array([u'DNMT3A', u'p.M880V', u'chr2', 25457249], dtype=object)
freqs = np.array([0.022831050228310501], dtype=object)
id = "id_23728"
```

The dimensions of `tmp`, `17232`, and `freqs` are as follows:

```
[in]  tmp.shape
[out] (4,)
[in]  np.array(17232).shape
[out] ()
[in]  freqs.shape
[out] (1,)
```

I have also tried casting them all as numpy arrays to no avail.

Although the variable `freqs` will frequently have more than one value.

However, with both the `np.concatenate` and `np.append` functions I get the following error:

```
*** ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

These all have the same number of columns `(0)`, why can't I concatenate them with either of the above described numpy methods?

All I'm looking to obtain is`[(tmp), 17232, (freqs)]` in one single dimensional array, which is to be appended onto the end of a pandas dataframe.

Thanks.

**Update**

It appears I can concatenate the two existing arrays:

```
np.concatenate([tmp, freqs],axis=0)
array([u'DNMT3A', u'p.M880V', u'chr2', 25457249, 0.022831050228310501], dtype=object)
```

However, the integer, even when casted cannot be used in concatenate.

```
np.concatenate([tmp, np.array(17571)],axis=0)
*** ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

What does work, however is nesting append and concatenate

```
np.concatenate((np.append(tmp, 17571), freqs),)
array([u'DNMT3A', u'p.M880V', u'chr2', 25457249, 17571,
       0.022831050228310501], dtype=object)
```

Although this is kind of messy. Does anyone have a better solution for concatenating a number of heterogeneous arrays?

Comment: Not great, but at least it doesn't care which things are 0d: `np.concatenate(map(np.atleast_1d, [tmp, id, freqs]))`

Comment: @askewchan that is nice, the atleast_1d function hadn't crossed my radar. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `id`, and later the `integer` `np.array(17571)`, are not an `array_like` object. See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html) how numpy decides whether an object can be converted automatically to a numpy array or not.

The solution is to make `id`   `array_like`, i.e. to be an element of a `list` or `tuple`, so that numpy understands that `id` belongs to a `1D` `array_like` structure

It all boils down to

```
concatenate((tmp, (id,), freqs))
```

or

```
concatenate((tmp, [id], freqs))
```

To avoid this sort of problems when dealing with input variables in functions using `numpy`, you can use `atleast_1d`, as pointed out by @askewchan. See about it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785237/overloading-a-float-to-a-numpy-array) question/answer.

Basically, if you are unsure if in different scenarios your variable `id` will be a single `str` or a list of `str`, you are better off using

```
concatenate((tmp, atleast_1d(id), freqs))
```

because the two options above will fail if `id` is already a list/tuple of strings.

EDIT: It may not be obvious why `np.array(17571)` is not an `array_like` object. This happens because `np.array(17571).shape==()`, so it is not iterable as it has no dimensions.